# RequireJS call back function to return value for keyevents

Tags: jquery, callback, requirejs, return

How can I use requireJS callback functions for getting value from a an event handler defined in external javascript file

```
<input type="text" id="shopprice" 
onkeypress= "require(['jqueryutils'],function(utils){var a =     
utils.keyPressPrice(event); alert(a); return a;});" ></input>
```

The event handler `utils.keyPressPrice` returns `false` for keycodes other than those for digits. The alert shows up results correctly (`true` for digits and `false` for non-digits). How can I make `onkeypress` event respond to this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `require` call is an inherently *asynchronous* call. You can't return a synchronous value from an asynchronous call. (There's a kind of synchronous version of `require` that RequireJS offers but it requires an asynchronous call before it, so it is not really a solution.) You could return a promise but the DOM is not designed to work with event handlers that return promises.

The right way to do what you want to do is this:

1. Produce an HTML that does **not** contain event handlers embedded in the HTML.
2. Write a RequireJS module that uses `addEventListener` or uses jQuery's `.on()` (it is as you wish) to add event handlers to the elements you care about. For instance:

   ```
   define(['jquery', 'jqueryutils'], function($, utils) {

   $("#shopprice").on("keypress", function (event) {
       var a = utils.keyPressPrice(event); 
       alert(a); 
       return a;
   });

   });
   ```
3. Require this module towards the end of your HTML file. If the module above is in a file named `handlers.js` you do `require(['handlers']);`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by setting event listeners in javascript and by calling handler in external script file.

```
$("#shopprice").keypress(function(e)
{
utils.keyPressPrice(e);
});
```